# Getting "Application Error" in heroku site with postgres db

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have written the code for rest api with node.js and postgres as db.
    Its running fine in postman in my system , I have deployed the same code to heroku its showing "Application Error" in heroku site. I have sequelize to connect db with node.js

```
My code :


const pg = require('pg');
var Sequelize=require ('sequelize');
var app  = require('express')();         // Express App include
var http = require('http').Server(app); // http server
var env = app.get('env') == 'development' ? 'dev' : app.get('env');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8086;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // Body parser for fetch posted data

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Body parser use JSON data

var sequelize = new Sequelize('testdb', 'postgres', 'Satya@9036', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres'
});
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

  app.get('/Getdata',function(req,res){
    var data = {
        "Data":""
    };



    //GET method 
     sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM test_table ", { replacements: { visible: 'true' },type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(function(test_table,err,rows) {
    // We don't need spread here, since only the results will be returned for select queries
    if(test_table)
    {
            data["Data"] = test_table;
            res.json(data);
        }
        else
        {
          data["Data"] = 'No data Found..';
          res.json(data);
        }

  });
});


When I run "heroku logs --tail --app boiling-river-40656 
" in terminal that shows following error.


**Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432**
2017-10-10T07:55:19.636702+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:123:14)
2017-10-10T07:55:19.636703+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-10-10T07:55:19.636701+00:00 app[web.1]:     at connection.connect.err (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:96:24)
2017-10-10T07:55:19.636703+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-10-10T07:55:19.636705+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Log says that you can't connect to 127.0.0.1:5432 on Heroku. There's no postgres server at 127.0.0.1:5432.
You should use **heroku postgres add-on**(It has free plan called "Hobby dev").

It's strictly recommended that you separate **dev** env from **heroku** env by declaring environment variables and consume it in your code.
Database url, pwd, user name should go to env or settings file.